# Get page number of bookmark in Reporting Service

Tags: reporting-services

I'd like to build Table of contents in Sql Server Reporting Services. I'm going to create textbox for each bookmark in report but I do not see any option to get page number. Am I missing something or it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge this is just not possible without some serious custom code that could pre-paginate the report while indexing bookmark locations and displaying the appropriate numbers based on the renderer used (pdf, html, excel etc).

For example, in one report I'm working on, it prints out as 53 pages (using the native print, PDF is 52 :/ ). However, when viewing it in the HTML renderer it's 30, and when using Excel it's 61 pages.

The page numbers for the bookmarks would differ greatly depending on what method you're viewing them on, and the code would have to figure all that out on its' own.